# immersions of spheres with handles minus disks

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

i am at a loss as far how exactly to immerse a sphere with genus g minus a disk into the plane. Thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't such a space just a regular neighborhood of a bouquet of circles?

Comment: I am not sure, how would you get to that conclusion if you had to describe the steps?

Comment: I'm not sure of the best way to see that.  Do you know how to construct a genus g surface from a polygon by identifying sides? That might be one way because then you're just deleting a disc from the center of the polygon.

Comment: i was thinking of using tori...
i am not sure how to use your method(still wrapping my mind around these concepts)

Comment: Maybe try to visualize it for a torus first. You should see how, if you make the hole wide enough, the space starts to look like two annuli stuck together (or a regular neighborhood of the wedge of two circles). For me its impossible to visualize for genus higher than that though ...

Comment: so here is my thinking: a sphere with a handle is a torus. So your argument applies. And if we increase the genus, we get a bouquet.  Is this the correct idea?

Comment: Yes, although I can't see how the induction would work.  The only way I see to really prove this is to use the fundamental polygon. Then if you delete a disc from the center its clear you get a bouquet of circles "thickened-up" to an open neighborhood (i.e. a regular neighborhood of the bouquet). Sorry I'm not more help.

Comment: Tim maybe you can help me with this problem, suppose i have $F:S^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{4}$ such that $F(x,y,z) = (x^{2} - y^{2}, xy, xz, yz).$ I wanna prove that $F$ gives rise to a smooth embedding from $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{4}.$ Thank you very much for you help

Comment: Tim's idea is pretty spot on, though I would be a bit careful. The immersion that you get will have your "bouquet of circles" crossing a number of times rather than only at the base point. In fact, you should get 2g pairwise overlapping circles. i.e. they all overlap at your base point and then you get pairs of circles which overlap once further on.

Comment: Your embedding of $RP^2$ is a pretty typical one. What have you tried so far?